# SQL Server compare AM with PM

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare `datetime`

Table1

```
ID  door    datetime
1   door1   2011-12-12 23:02
2   door1   2011-11-11 20:52 
3   door2   2011-12-13 19:17
```

Table2

```
ID  door    datetime
1   door2   2011-12-12 02:02
2   door3   2011-11-11 01:52 
3   door4   2011-12-13 20:17 
4   door2   2012-12-09 11:10
5   door2   2012-12-11 23:54
```

I want to update/overwrite the rows of `table2` with those of `table1` by comparing the `id` and `datetime`

Final results

Table2

```
ID  door    datetime
1   door1   2011-12-12 23:02
2   door1   2011-11-11 20:52 
3   door2   2011-12-13 19:17 
4   door2   2012-12-09 11:10
5   door2   2012-12-11 23:54
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Where is AM vs PM coming into the question?

Comment: 2011-12-12 23:02 vs 2011-12-12 02:02 time is in 24 hour format

Comment: I'm aware of that... but my question stands. You have not mentioned anything about exactly what the comparison is, and what should be happening. I could take a guess from your `Final Results` table, but that would be exactly that... a guess.  (Also, when replying to a comment, you need to put `@` followed the username, otherwise the user will not get a notification. You are receiving a notification for this because I am commenting on *your* post)